# Set svg text in img source from another page

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, svg

I have two aspx pages. The first page has this code.

**Page1.aspx**

```
<img src="Page2.aspx" />
```

The second page has this code in the code behind.

**Page2.aspx**

```
Dim svgString as String = "<svg height="100" width="100"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" /></svg>"
Dim newSVGString as String = Uri.EscapeUriString(svgString)

Response.Clear()
Response.Write(newSVGString)
Response.End()
```

Is there any way to display my svg which is generated in Page2.aspx to Page1.aspx? I tried the `MemoryStream` then pass the value in the `Response.BinaryWrite()` but it still does not work.

Comment: Store it in a cookie (if it's small enough) and then read it out from the cookie in the other page. If it's too big for a cookie, local storage. Will that do?

Comment: But we wouldn't know how big the SVG file would be. So storing it in a cookie won't be the best way. T_T

Comment: [Local storage then](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)

Comment: Possible. However in the long run, SVGs will become many and server space would then be an issue. So I think it's also not possible...

Can it be displayed to something like this? http://www.dotnetperls.com/response-binarywrite

Comment: What's local storage (which is a browser feature) got to do with server space? What is your issue really? Is it how to send data between pages or is it how to display an SVG I've created on a page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the content  of your response to `image/svg+xml`

```
 Response.ContentType = "image/svg+xml"
```

then you don't need to escape your svg string, just do

```
Dim svgString as String = "<svg height="100" width="100"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" /></svg>"


Response.Clear()
Response.Write(newString)
Response.End()
```

try it with just browsing to your page2.aspx. if that works, it works in `<img/>` as well